# Одним махом семерых побивахом

Tags: пословицы

Благодаря моей догадке, подтвержденной словарем Academic.ru, я уже выяснил, что это словосочетание означает:

> *Народн. Ирон.* Быстро, не сомневаясь и не раздумывая, справиться с чем-л.  Выражение возникло под влиянием оборота одним ударом семерых из сказки братьев Гримм «Храбрый портняжка» (1814 г.). Форма (аористная) убивахом (побивахом) стилизована под старославянский.

Что значит *семерых*? Существует ли вообще ещё аорист в русском языке? Есть ли у него такое же значение, как у древнегреческого аориста?

Answer (score 5):

> Что значит *семерых*?

*Семерых* is acc. of *семеро*, which is the collective form of the numeral *семь* ("seven").

It's used with animate masculine or neuter nouns denoting sentient beings to describe sets of such beings: *двое рабочих, пятеро строителей, семеро богов*.

The meaning is similar to English "pair" or "dozen" (but extends to all numbers from 2 to 10), and directly corresponds to Polish *troje*, *siedmioro* etc.

> Существует ли вообще ещё аорист в русском языке?

No it does not. All past forms had been replaced with a single past form originating from perfect.

> Есть ли у него такое же значение, как у древнегреческого аориста?

Church Slavonic uses aorist in pretty much the same way Modern English uses past simple: to describe one-off, integral events in past.

Note that this form (*убивахом*) is plural and imperfect ("we used to kill") and is here only for styling purposes. It's ungrammatical if parsed according to Church Slavonic rules.

Answer (score 3):

*Семерых* - это винительный падеж от *семеро*. Это форма числительного, именуемая *собирательная*. Например, *семеро одного не ждут*; *трое в лодке, не считая собаки*; *двое - это компания, а трое - уже толпа* и т.п.

*Аорист* в современном русском языке не используется, хотя попадаются вот такие отдельные реликты. Насчёт истории, вопрос довольно сложный, так как аорист присутствует и в церковнославянском, и в древнерусском языках. Церковнославянский же язык, как известно, был создан "с оглядкой" на древнегреческий.